# Directional derivative $f(x,y)=\frac{x^3}{1+x^2+y^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I'm stuck on calculating the directional derivative of $f(x,y)=\frac{x^3}{1+x^2+y^2}$ in $(3,-1)$ along $(a,b)\in\mathbb{R}^2$.

My try: $\lim\limits_{t\to 0}\frac{f((3,-1)+t(a,b))-f(3,-1)}{t}=\lim\limits_{t\to 0}\frac{\frac{(3+ta)^3}{1+(3+ta)^2+(-1+tb)^2}-\frac{27}{11}}{t}=\lim\limits_{t\to 0}\frac{(3+ta)^3}{t(1+(3+ta)^2+(-1+tb)^2)}-\frac{27}{t11}$ if I compute... I get zero.... There must be a mistake

Comment: Are you familiar with the differential or the gradient? This function is clearly smooth, and hence its directional derivatives can be calculated using the gradient.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is allowed for me to use this. Then I first have to proof that f is smooth.

Answer (score 1):

In order to show that $f$ is derivable in $(3, -1)$ note that both the numerator and the denominator are polynomials, which are known to be derivable. Next, the denominator does not cancel in $(3, -1)$, therefore the fraction is well-defined and, being a fraction of derivable functions, is itself derivable in $(3, -1)$.

The directional derivative of a derivable function $f$ computed in a point $(x_0, y_0)$ along a vector $(a, b)$ is ${\partial f \over \partial x} (x_0, y_0) \cdot a + {\partial f \over \partial y} (x_0, y_0) \cdot b$, where $\cdot$ is the usual multiplication of numbers.

In your case, this gives ${x^2 (3 + x^2 + 3y^2) \over (1 + x^2 + y^2)^2} (3,-1) \cdot a - {2 x^3 y \over 1 + x^2 + y^2} (3,-1) \cdot b = {135 \over 121} a - {54 \over 121} b$.

Comment: Or more elequantly $u=(a,v)$ then $f'(x,y)'_u=\nabla f(x,y)\cdot u$